# Android listview setOnItemClickListener change image background by position by switch

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, onitemclicklistener

I am working on `BaseAdapter`. I wrote some code which can show images and text in `listview` with `baseAdapter`. Now i want to change images and text background by position.

this is a my `baseAdapter` code

```
    public class SlideMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] menu_items_id;

    private final int[] Imageid;
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public SlideMenuAdapter(Context context, String[] names, int[] Imageid)
             {
        mContext = context;

        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.menu_items_id = names;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return Imageid.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View grid;

        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_slidemenu_adaper, null);
        textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        textView.setText(menu_items_id[position]);


        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        return grid;
    }
}
```

and this is a my listview listener code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)parent.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8f332a"));
                imageView.setImageResource(menu_imagesover[position]);
                break;

            case 1:
                textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                imageView.setImageResource(menu_imagesover[position]);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    });


int[] menu_imagesover = { R.drawable.schedule_ove, R.drawable.about_over,
        R.drawable.booking_over };
```

when I click in listview I can only change first item 's images and text background. how I can write code to can change each item by position?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `invalidate` method to refresh your `listview` :

```
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8f332a"));
            imageView.setImageResource(menu_imagesover[position]);
            break;

        case 1:
            textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            imageView.setImageResource(menu_imagesover[position]);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        invalidate(); //add here
```

Or if its not working, try to call `invalidateViews` instead of `invalidate`.

And i think theres something fishy about `switch (position)`, doesnt it means your code will only work if the 1st and 2nd row is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Take ArrayList with Hashmap which hold all info for list item :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String,Object> row1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
row1.put("name","item1");
row1.put("normalImage",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
row1.put("selectedImage",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
row1.put("normalTextColor","#000000");
row1.put("selectedTextColor","#ff0000");
row1.put("isClick",false);
listData.add(row1);
SlideMenuAdapter adapter = new SlideMenuAdapter(context,listData);
```

Change state of particular list item click

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        if((Boolean)listData.get(position).get("isClick")){
           listData.get(position).put("isClick",false);
        }else{
           listData.get(position).put("isClick",true);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Check item click state in getView() adapter :

```
public class SlideMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data;

    public SlideMenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.azercell_slidemenu_adaper, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(data.get(position).get("name").toString());
        if((Boolean)data.get(position).get("isClick")){
            holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(data.get(position).get("selectedTextColor").toString()));
            holder.imageView.setImageResource((Integer)data.get(position).get("selectedImage"));
        }else{
            holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(data.get(position).get("normalTextColor").toString()));
            holder.imageView.setImageResource((Integer)data.get(position).get("normalImage"));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i have 3 images and text and for example if i click second item  then i must change only second images  and etc....

Comment: Please add as no of list item data in ArrayList here I'm only use one item which is row1 HashMap so you can take row2,row3,etc as no list item all other things already handle in adapter.